# Import shared code in Next.js app in a monorepo

Tags: typescript, next.js, monorepo

I want to leverage monorepo by reusing types, DTOs, and other isomorphic app stuff from the backend (Nest.js) services within the same mono repo. In my case the next.js app and the nest.js app (which is a nest.js monorepo on its own) are on the same level in the root dir. I'm re-exporting a bunch of files in the `nest-app/libs/types/src/index.ts` and then import it in my next.js app. But when I do so, next.js complains with **Failed to compile** error

The easiest way to reproduce the error is to do the following

- create an arbitrary folder for the monorepo, like `test-import`
- navigate to the monorepo folder (`cd test-import`)
- run `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript` and choose a name for the project (like `next-app`)
- create the below `external.ts` file in the root of the monorepo (on the same level as the `next-app`)
- run `npm run dev` from the `next-app` folder

Monorepo structure:

```
external.ts
next-app
  (other files omitted)
  pages
    index.tsx
```

**external.ts**

```
export type ExternalType = string;

export const me = "ME";
```

`next-app/pages/index.tsx` is importing content of `external.ts`

```
import { me } from "../../external";

// boilerplate code omitted
<h1 className={styles.title}>
  Welcome {me} to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
</h1>
```

The following error is thrown:

```
../external.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> export type ExternalType = string;
| 
| export const me = "ME";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the experimental `externalDir` feature: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/22867.

```
// next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  experimental: {
    externalDir: true
  }
}
```

I have checked that it works at least in the case you have described.

---

This said, we also have a Nest+Next monorepo — although in our case the shared code is outside of both Next and Nest — and to get it working we had to resort to symlinking (`ln -s`) the shared code into the Nest folder. If you ever decide to have a folder with shared code that exists outside both the Next and Nest codebases, you might want to try this as well.

IIRC there is a way to get it working without a symlink but for that Nest has to manage the whole monorepo, including non-Nest subprojects.

Comment: It worked out nicely! Thanks a lot! My design decision was to keep DTOs (and related stuff) closer to the `api-gateway` service, which is a Nest.js app. It'd be nice if you could share some links about good designs decisions on how to connect these kind of stuff in a monorepo

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have enough experience here to give advice — sorry.